# Qt - easiest way to convert int to file size format (KB, MB or GB)?

Tags: qt

What is the easiest way to convert `int` of file size to string in file size format like:

```
2048 to 2 KB
4086 KB to 4 MB
```

instead of calculating it manually in Qt5?

Comment: What's the problem about calculating it?

Comment: No problem actually. Just want to know if Qt provide a way to do this easily (like `hurry.filesize` in python).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

QFileInfo doesn't have a method specific for that, but [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/34914) you can find a simple implementation subclassing QFileInfo and implementing this new method

```
QString QFileInfoHumanSize::size_human()
{
    float num = this->size();
    QStringList list;
    list << "KB" << "MB" << "GB" << "TB";

    QStringListIterator i(list);
    QString unit("bytes");

    while(num >= 1024.0 && i.hasNext())
     {
        unit = i.next();
        num /= 1024.0;
    }
    return QString().setNum(num,'f',2)+" "+unit;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to have `list` as a constant class member. There's no reason to keep creating the list every time you want to use it since the list will always be the same.

Comment: @RobbieE I guess that's premature optimization. Smart compiler will remove multiple creations of the list and making the list static makes code less readable

Answer (score 30):

Qt 5.10 has introduced [ready solution](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#formattedDataSize):

```
QLocale locale = this->locale();
QString valueText = locale.formattedDataSize(sizeValue);
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: @BPL this was added almost 3 years after accepted answer ;).

Comment: @BPL agree, helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Code provided by @danielfranca results in slightly incorrect results if used with int rather than floats. Here is a more accurate version for reporting the result as an integer:

```
QString MyClass::convertFileSizeToHumanReadable(const qlonglong & bytes)
{
    QString number;

    if(bytes < 0x400) //If less than 1 KB, report in B
    {
        number = QLocale::system().toString(bytes);
        number.append(" B");
        return number;
    }
    else
    {
        if(bytes >= 0x400 && bytes < 0x100000) //If less than 1 MB, report in KB, unless rounded result is 1024 KB, then report in MB
        {
            qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x400 / 2)) / 0x400;

            if(result < 0x400)
            {
                number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                number.append(" KB");
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x100000 / 2)) / 0x100000;
                number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                number.append(" MB");
                return number;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(bytes >= 0x100000 && bytes < 0x40000000) //If less than 1 GB, report in MB, unless rounded result is 1024 MB, then report in GB
            {
                qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x100000 / 2)) / 0x100000;

                if(result < 0x100000)
                {
                    number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                    number.append(" MB");
                    return number;
                }
                else
                {
                    qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x40000000 / 2)) / 0x40000000;
                    number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                    number.append(" GB");
                    return number;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(bytes >= 0x40000000 && bytes < 0x10000000000) //If less than 1 TB, report in GB, unless rounded result is 1024 GB, then report in TB
                {
                    qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x40000000 / 2)) / 0x40000000;

                    if(result < 0x40000000)
                    {
                        number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                        number.append(" GB");
                        return number;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x10000000000 / 2)) / 0x10000000000;
                        number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                        number.append(" TB");
                        return number;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    qlonglong result = (bytes + (0x10000000000 / 2)) / 0x10000000000; //If more than 1 TB, report in TB
                    number = QLocale::system().toString(result);
                    number.append(" TB");
                    return number;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```